# Using MySQL partitioning by an AUTO INCREMENT field, how can I guarantee that INSERT/LOAD DATA statements are only accessing specified partitions?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning, dml

**General context**

I want to be able to tell, when inserting into non-balanced `RANGE`-partitioned MySQL tables with `AUTO INCREMENT` primary keys, whether my inserts are causing MySQL to communicate in any way with partitions other than the ones I specify. This is useful for budgeting future capacity for large-scale data loading; with that assurance, I could much more accurately predict that performance and hardware resource cost of loading data into the database.

I am using MySQL 5.6.

**Specific context**

Say I have the following table in MySQL (5.6):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
/*!12345 PARTITION BY RANGE (id)
(PARTITION cold VALUES LESS THAN (8000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION hot VALUES LESS THAN (9000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION overflow VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Assume the table is not sparse: no rows have been deleted, so `count(*) = max(id) = 9001`.

**Questions**

- If I do `INSERT INTO foo (data) PARTITION (hot) VALUES ('abc')` or an equivalent `LOAD DATA` statement with the `PARTITION` clause included, are any partitions other than the selected `hot` partition being accessed?
- How would I tell what partitions are being accessed by those DML statements?

**What I've tried**

The MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations-locking.html) on partition selection says:

> REPLACE and INSERT now lock only those partitions having rows to be
>   inserted or replaced. However, if an AUTO_INCREMENT value is generated
>   for any partitioning column then all partitions are locked.

Additionally, it says:

> Locks imposed by LOAD DATA statements on partitioned tables cannot be
>   pruned.

Those statements don't help clarify which partitions are being accessed by DML queries *which explicitly specify the partition*.

I've tried doing `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS INSERT INTO foo ...`, but the `partitions` column of the output is always `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-selection.html),

> For statements that insert rows, the behavior differs in that failure to find a suitable partition causes the statement to fail. This is true for both INSERT and REPLACE statements

So when you try to insert a row that does not match your specified partition, you'll receive

> Error Code: 1748. Found a row not matching the given partition set

This including statements where some rows match and some don't, 
so you cannot use this to fill "hot" and throw away rows that would go into "overflow" (as the whole query will fail).

The `explain`-otuput for MySQL 5.6 does not include a seperate row for `insert`; the value for `partition` relates to the source of the data you insert (in cases where you  e.g. use `insert ... select ... partition ...`), even if you use `values()` (then you use "no table", and the relevant partition is just `null`). For MySQL 5.7+, there is an "insert"-type, and it would indeed list only your specified partition.